# Google play game services with 2 Fragment screens

Tags: android, google-play-games, multiplayer

I want to create a multiplayer game with Google Play Services. There is no problem so far if I implement everything in one fragment. However, I don't know what to do if I want to have 2 different fragments.

HomeScreen: handle find quick match, invite friends, accept friend request,...

PlayScreen: just play game

in HomeScreen, I setup the game with RoomConfig and callback objects

```
    // Create the room configuration.
    val roomBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(mRoomUpdateCallback)
            .setOnMessageReceivedListener(mMessageReceivedHandler)
            .setRoomStatusUpdateCallback(mRoomStatusCallbackHandler)
            .addPlayersToInvite(invitees)
    mJoinedRoomConfig = roomBuilder.build()
    mJoinedRoomConfig?.let {
        getMultiplayerClient()?.create(it)
    }
```

when the other player connect, I start the GameScreen Fragment:

```
    override fun onConnectedToRoom(room: Room?) {
        Logger.d("RoomStatusUpdateCallback::onConnectedToRoom")
        navigateToPlay()
    }
```

I stuck here as I don't know how to setup the game in PlayScreen Fragment. Should I create a new RoomConfig and new callback handlers? Or how to make PlayScreen listen to all events from game?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by peer to peer connection please go through below url

```
https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-peer-to-peer-multiplayer-networked-game--gamedev-10074
```

for local connection

```
https://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question is not how to create a multi player game